# How to get data and post to DB in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created a form and want to post those data to DB but no error and no data build up after submitted.

the Model I created:

```
class BillingAddress(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
apartment_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
district = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Th forms.py in my project

```
class CheckOutForm(forms.Form):
street_address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
apartment_address = forms.CharField(required=False)
district = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'custom-select d-block w-100',}), 
choices=DISTRICT_CHOICES,)
same_billing_address = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())
save_info = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())
payment = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES)
```

The html code:

```
<form method="POST" class="card-body">
          {% csrf_token %}

          <h3>Shipping address</h3>

          <div class='hideable_shipping_form'>

            <div class="md-form mb-5">
                <label for="street_address" class="">Address</label>
                {{ form.street_address }}.....
```

views.py. I think I might wrong here but I can't figure it out

```
def checkout(request):
form = CheckOutForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method == 'POST':
        street_address = form.cleaned_data.get('street_address')
        apartment_address = form.cleaned_data.get('apartment_address')
        district = form.cleaned_data.get('district')
        same_billing_address = form.cleaned_data.get('same_billing_address')
        save_info = form.cleaned_data.get('save_info')
        payment = form.cleaned_data.get('payment')
        billing_address = BillingAddress(
            user=request.user,
            street_address=street_address,
            apartment_address=apartment_address,
            district=district,
        )
        billing_address.save()
        return redirect('checkout')
else:
    form = CheckOutForm()
context = {
    'form': form
}
return render(request, 'product/checkout.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi your solution does't contains `is_valid` form method call that mean your form `cleaned_data` or `errors` was not filled and thats why nothing happens with your model instance.

To solve this case you can call `is_valid` before getting data from `cleaned_data`. If data inside your form is not valid you can see what's wrong data was sended and render it on response.

Also you can provide model based form generation using `ModelForm` as base class of your form:

```
from django import forms

class BillingAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BillingAddress
        fields = ['street_address', 'apartment_address', 'district']
```

If you need have some extra fields for data validation you can declare it as simple django form fields and append it into fields attribute of model meta:

```
from django import forms
    
class BillingAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    same_billing_address = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())

    class Meta:
        model = BillingAddress
        fields = ['street_address', 'apartment_address', 'district', 'same_billing_address']
```

After your form will be ready you should just call `is_valid` method:

```
form = BillingAddressForm(request.POST)
form.is_valid()
```

Also you can use some of generic views that's work in synergy with model form.

Please visit [Form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/) and [Creating forms from models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) for more information.